# Extract all lines of a file between 2 delimiters without them in VBScript Regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

I try to Extract all lines of a file between 2 strings in another file and without these delimiters.
Example:

```
[General]
Description=Description 

[extractSection]
First Line extracted. It is not an ini section 

Last Line extracted 

[OthersSection]
blablabla
```

It seems to work with this script. One of my first vbs.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "E:\Temp\Test.txt"
strTemp = "E:\Temp\Temp.txt"
If objFS.FileExists(strTemp) Then objFS.DeleteFile(strTemp)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
  If isReading = True Then
    If instr(strline,"[") Then
      Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp, True)
      objOutFile.Write(strLine1)
      objOutFile.Close
      Exit Do
    Else
      strline1 = strline1 & strline & vbNewLine
    End If
  Else
    If instr(LCase(strline),"[extractsection]") Then
      isReading = True
    End If 
  End If
Loop
objFile.Close
```

But it seems not very optimized, I have files up to 8Mb.
I would like to try the same thing using Regex. I never used, I have to learn.
I have this as beginning: `\[extractsection\]([\s\S]*?)\[[\s\S]`
But I would like without the delimiters.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read these "big" files in memory? In order to match multiline blocks of text, you need to read the whole file into memory first, and sometimes it is worse than using "not very optimized" but working code.

Comment: I do not know much, I'm just looking for the best solution.  I will have a lot of files to process but not all that big.

Comment: Then read it in and use `\[extractSection]\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*(?=\n\s*\[|$)` to extract Group 1 value using `match.Submatches(0)`. To improve performance, you may try using `\[extractSection](.*(?:\n(?!\[).*)*)`

Comment: Since the files appear to be in INI format, 8 MB isn't that big on modern systems, and parsing INI files is a rather well-solved problem, I'd recommend using something like the [`ParseIni`](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/parseini.shtml) function I wrote a couple years back. It reads the file into a dictionary using the section titles as keys.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd is almost good \[extractSection](.*(?:\n(?!\[).*)*) but it remains the first delimiter. Angsar, it is not a real INI format some section yes, others no and not the one I want to extract

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wiktor. It seems it is OK with `(?<=\[extractSection\]\n)(.*(?:\n(?!\[).*)*)` Just let me know what is best (Ram | speed) vs my ReadLine script on top, please

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this vbscript **without a Regex** :

```
Option Explicit
Dim strFile,strTemp,Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter,Extracted_Data
strFile = "E:\Temp\Test.txt"
strTemp = "E:\Temp\Temp.txt"
Full_String = ReadFileText(strFile)
First_Delimiter = "[extractSection]"
Second_Delimiter = "[OthersSection]"
Extracted_Data = String_Between(Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter)
wscript.echo Extracted_Data
Write2File Extracted_Data,strTemp
'************************************************************************************************
Function String_Between(ByVal Full_String, ByVal First_Delimiter, ByVal Second_Delimiter)
Dim Pos,Pos2
Pos = InStr(Full_String, First_Delimiter)
Pos2 = InStr(Full_String, Second_Delimiter)
If Pos = 0 Or Pos2 = 0 Then
    String_Between = "Missing Delimiter"
    Exit Function
End If
String_Between = Mid(Full_String, Pos + Len(First_Delimiter), Pos2 - (Pos + Len(First_Delimiter)))
End Function
'***********************************************************************************************
Function ReadFileText(sFile)
    Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        MsgBox "CRITICAL ERROR " & VbCrLF & "The File "& DblQuote(sFile) &_
        " dosen't exists !",VbCritical,"CRITICAL ERROR"
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        Set oTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)
        sText = oTS.ReadAll
        oTS.close
        set oTS = nothing
        Set objFSO = nothing
        ReadFileText = sText
    End if
End Function 
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub Write2File(strText,OutputFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(OutputFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

And this one **with RegEx**

```
Option Explicit
Dim strFile,strTemp,Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter,Extracted_Data
strFile = "E:\Temp\Test.txt"
strTemp = "E:\Temp\Temp.txt"
Full_String = ReadFileText(strFile)
First_Delimiter = "[extractSection]"
Second_Delimiter = "[OthersSection]"
Extracted_Data = ExtractData(Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter)
wscript.echo Extracted_Data
Write2File Extracted_Data,strTemp
'***********************************************************************************************
Function ExtractData(Full_String,Start_Delim,End_Delim)
Dim fso,f,r,Matches,Contents,Data
    Start_Delim = Replace(Start_Delim,"[","\[")
    Start_Delim = Replace(Start_Delim,"]","\]")
    End_Delim = Replace(End_Delim,"[","\[")
    End_Delim = Replace(End_Delim,"]","\]")
    Set r=new regexp
    r.pattern = "(?:^|(?:\r\n))(:?"& Start_Delim &"\r\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:\r\n)(?:"& End_Delim &")"
    Set Matches = r.Execute(Full_String)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then Data = Matches(0).SubMatches(1)
    ExtractData = Data
End Function
'***********************************************************************************************
Function ReadFileText(sFile)
    Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        MsgBox "CRITICAL ERROR " & VbCrLF & "The File "& DblQuote(sFile) &_
        " dosen't exists !",VbCritical,"CRITICAL ERROR"
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        Set oTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)
        sText = oTS.ReadAll
        oTS.close
        set oTS = nothing
        Set objFSO = nothing
        ReadFileText = sText
    End if
End Function 
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub Write2File(strText,OutputFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(OutputFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```